# Resolve assemblies through app.config for Mono Cecil

Tags: .net, reflection, mono, .net-assembly, mono.cecil

I've written a tool that uses Mono Cecil to analyse various parts of our application's codebase; it relies on being able to resolve a TypeReference (which involves finding the assembly that contains the TypeDefinition). This works fine if I feed it a list of paths where DLLs can be found.

However, our application's dependencies are somewhat complicated, and we have an app.config that makes heavy use of `<bindingRedirect>` and `<codeBase>` elements to guide .NET's assembly resolver. For instance, we have a directory structure organised by DLL version, we redirect old version numbers to the latest, and we can load two versions of a DLL at the same time (when we have breaking changes, we can run a 1.x and a 2.x version within the same process).

I'd like my Cecil-based tool to obey the same rules. Is there a way I can take advantage of the existing app.config?

- Can I ask .NET to translate an assembly name into a DLL path without actually loading the assembly? (This is a tool that reports on broken DLLs, so the assembly may not load successfully.)
- Alternatively, is there already an open-source implementation of the algorithm .NET uses to locate an assembly at runtime?